# Flask return multiple variables?

Tags: python, flask

I am learning Flash with Python. My python skills are okay, but I have no experience with web apps. I have a form that takes some information and I want to display it back after it is submitted. I can do that part, however I can only return one variable from that form even tho there are 3 variables in the form. I can return each one individually but not all together. If I try all 3, I get a 500 error. Here is the code I am working with:

```
from flask import Blueprint
from flask import render_template
from flask import request

simple_page = Blueprint('simple_page', __name__)

@simple_page.route('/testing', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def my_form():
        if request.method=='GET':
            return render_template("my-form.html")
        elif request.method=='POST':
            firstname = request.form['firstname']
            lastname = request.form['lastname']
            cellphone = request.form['cellphone']
            return firstname, lastname, cellphone
```

If I change the last return line to:

```
return firstname
```

it works, or:

```
return lastname
```

or:

```
return cellphone
```

If I try two variables it will only return the first, once I add the 3rd I get the 500 error. I am sure I am doing something silly, but even with tons of googling I could not get it figured out. Any help would be great. Thank you.

Comment: Flask views can't return a tuple. You probably want to pass those as arguments to a template.

Comment: Flask view functions _can_ return multiple values but not in the way you want to use them here. See #4 in the documentation [here](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#about-responses).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Flask requires either a `str` or `Response` to be return, in you case you are attempting to return a `tuple`.

You can either return your `tuple` as a formatted `str`

```
return  '{} {} {}'.format(firstname, lastname, cellphone)
```

Or you can pass the values into another `template`

```
return render_template('my_other_template.html', 
                       firstname=firstname,
                       lastname=lastname,
                       cellphone=cellphone)
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. You can pass as many variables as needed I suppose?

Comment: @ChristopherNelson That is correct, you can pass in as many variables as you like

Comment: I tried the new print format and it works too, e.g. `return f"Book id = {book['id']}, published in {book['year_published']}, authored by {book['author']}<p>title = {book['title']}"

Comment: You could also create a tuple of firstname lastname and cellphone and then typeconvert it to a string.             
output = (firstname, lastname, cellphone)
output = str(output)
return output

And when you want to use the return values from within Python again just use ast.literal_eval(return_string) to get a 3-tuple